# How to specify cell when copying cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open a few workbooks in a folder to pull some data to the ThisWorkbook. I'm having problems with Cells notation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateAttendance()
    GetData
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim wbFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\8865\Documents\excel\relationships\registers\regs")
    Dim y As Long

    y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each wbFile In folder.Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1)).Value = ws.Range("E19").Value --> Doesn't Work
            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 2)).Value = ws.Range("E35").Value --> Doesn't work
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = ws.Range("E35").Value ' --> Works fine but I need to loop it to change the row so I have to use Cells
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = ws.Range("E19").Value ' --> works fine but I need to loop it to change the row so I have to use Cells
            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Value = ws.Range("E19, E35, E40").Value --> Is it possible to do something like that?

            y = y + 1
        Next ws

        wb.Close
        End If

    Next wbFile

End Sub
```

See above, I put some comments at the end of the line to indicate what works and what doesn't.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I'd do the following about iterating but it throws an error

> Runtime error 1004, Application defined or object defined error)

```
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each wbFile In folder.Files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(y, 1)).Value = ws.Range("E19").Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(y, 2)).Value = ws.Range("E35").Value
            y = y + 1
        Next ws

        wb.Close
    End If

Next wbFile
```

Comment: You are correctly incrementing **y**, but your are not using it in the loop, you keep overwriting **A1** and **B1** in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: I know that. It's because my first 2 lines with Cells(x, y) notation (commented out) throw errors so I cannot iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second coding example, replace:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(y, 1)).Value = ws.Range("E19").Value
```

with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value = ws.Range("E19").Value
```

You don't need `Cells()` within `Range()`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through w/o Increase

With `y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` you calculate the last row of data, so you have to increase it by one whenever a condition is met and use it as the row parameter in the Cells property `.Cells(y, "A")` (or the Range property `.range("A" & y)`).

```
Private Sub GetData()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim wbFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\8865\Documents\excel\relationships\registers\regs")
    Dim y As Long

    y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each wbFile In folder.Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            y = y + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, "A").Value = ws.Range("E35").Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, "B").Value = ws.Range("E19").Value
        Next ws

        wb.Close
        End If

    Next wbFile

End Sub
```